# emacs ESS ess-execute-screen-options to width - 2

Tags: r, emacs, ess

I love how ESS can auto-adjust the R process's width to match the emacs window width (with `ess-execute-screen-options`), but ... I'd like to set the process to the width *minus 2 characters* ... anyone have any idea how'd I'd do that?

Comment: The docs say that it sets to *"1 less than the window width"*. While I wondered if it were a hard-coded "1", it looks in [the code](https://github.com/emacs-ess/ESS/blob/f12ce843728b5623cee9a7cb977c90c49657eda6/lisp/ess-inf.el#L2088) as if the `floor` function might be what is giving it the "1 less", not an actual number. I see utility in what you're asking for, perhaps you should ask as a feature-request?